# How can I batch-prepend shebang lines to all scripts in a directory?

Tags: linux, macos, path, shebang

Let's say I have a script that I can use via

```
python /path/to/my/scripts/somescript.py input.txt output.txt
```

but I would like to call it like this:

```
`somescript.py input.txt output.txt`
```

from the command line

Okay, no problem, I just add it to my PATH and add a shebang on top of it. However, I have whole directory of scripts which I want to modify like this. How would I automate this process?

With the following command I could append the shebang to one script for example, but it seems that it doesn't like the "#!" part...

```
 exec 3<> test.py && awk -v TEXT=echo "#!/Users/sebastian/miniconda3/bin/python" 'BEGIN {print TEXT}{print}' test.py >&3
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I just wanted to add my final solution to this problem - thanks to the great help by @sehe

It would be in form of a shell script:

```
# Shell script that prepends a Python shebang 
# '#!/usr/bin/env python' to all
# Python script files in the current directory
# so that script files can be executed via
# >> myscript.py 
# instead of 
# >> python myscript.py

# prepends '#!/usr/bin/env python' to all .py files

find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py" -exec sed -i.bak '1i\
#!/usr/bin/env python
' {} \;

# removes temporary files
find . -name "*.bak" -exec rm -rf {} \;

# makes Python scripts executable
chmod ug+x *.py
```

Comment: I've modified the tags to reflect the intended platform (not (just) "UNIX"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sed script (`script.sed`):

```
1 i\
#!/usr/bin/python
```

And use it:

```
sed -i -f script.sed *.py
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65303d5f25f82dfa)** (although I've named the script `main.cpp` there for ... pragmatic reasons :))

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't work on MacOS though, I get a '"command c expects \ followed by text"'

Comment: command c? Did you make a typo? Did you have whitespace following `\`? Did you ... save the file with the wrong (non-Mac) line-ends?

Comment: No, I didn't have any unusual line ends. I read in other posts that this is particular Mac OS issue, it needs the tmp files

Comment: Yeah, sed has slightly different sets of options across platforms - but you didn't really specify the platform. Also, it's customary to upvote helpful answers, and accept the one that solved your issue (you could _even_ "correct" my answer for your added requirements)

Comment: Thank you, that I was a little bit unclear about the platform, I didn't expect this difference between Unix on MacOS and Linux initially. Your answer was really helpful and led me to the right track, thanks for that! Btw. I have a small follow-up question that I added to the solution that worked for me below: how can I insert contents from a variable into the text that I want to prepend via `sed`?

Comment: Hm, then I get into trouble with the shebang again '-bash: !/usr/bin/python: event not found'

Comment: @SebastianRaschka escape the ! (`\!`) (it's history expansion). Gave me no trouble on linux, but hey :)

Comment: oh well, you can always go the annoying way and combine `'#!this'"$STYLE"'of quoting'`

Comment: Oh great that's it, thank you, finally solved the problem. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: okay, I went a step back and decided to add the shebang as '#!/usr/bin/env python' for a more general solution (so that the shell can figure out which "python" is currently used). I added the solution at the bottom of my initial question. Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just found a solution that works for me on both Linux and Mac via a shell script that will prepend the shebang to all .py files in the current directory

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py" -exec sed -i.bak '1i\
#!/usr/bin/python
' {} \;

find . -name "*.bak" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

As a follow up, how would I swap in contents from a variable into the text added by `sed`?

E.g., this won't work

```
python3_ver=$(which python3)

find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py" -exec sed -i.bak '1i\
#!${python3_ver}
' {} \;

find . -name "*.bak" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Of course you can put the sed script on the command line, but I thought the script would be a lot clearer. How's this different from my answer? Also `find . -name '*.bak' -delete` would be more concise